# How to get all IP's from a IPv6 Subnet in Java?

Tags: java, ipv6

I am implementing the IPv6 support in Java using the "java-ipv6-0.17" jar ?

I have got the start range and end range using the code below but I need all the IP's in the given subnet ?

```
import com.googlecode.ipv6.IPv6NetworkMask;

public class IP {

public static void main(String[] args) {

final IPv6Network strangeNetwork = IPv6Network.fromString("2001:0db8::/31");
System.out.println("Start Range:"+ " "+ strangeNetwork.getFirst());
System.out.println("End Range:"+ " "+ strangeNetwork.getLast() + "\n");
```

**Output :**

Start Range: 2001:db8::

End Range: 2001:db9:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff

Could anyone please help and provide the code snippet ?

Comment: That's... 2^96 addresses. You almost certainly don't want to "get" them all.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really bad idea to do this since as the comments say, you can't possibly store all the addresses, but as a learning experience, you can iterate over a range of `IPv6Address` using `IPv6AddressRange`. Since `IPv6AddressRange` implements `Iterable`, we can run through it with an enhanced for loop:

```java
List<IPv6Address> ipList = new ArrayList<>();

IPv6AddressRange range = IPv6AddressRange.fromFirstAndLast(
  IPv6Address.fromString("2001:db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000"), 
  IPv6Address.fromString("2001:db9:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff"));

for (IPv6Address addr : range) {
  ipList.add(addr);
}
```